# Printing Excel sheet using PdfCreator .NET COM wrapper

Tags: c#, excel, pdf, com, pdf-generation

I have a little class that works with older [PDF Creator](http://docs.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator/3.1/en/) before version 2. It prints an Excel worksheet to a specified PDF file using `PDF Creator` printer thus creating a PDF File at the specified path.

```
public class PDFCreatorHelper
{
    //Global Deceleration        
    private clsPDFCreator  _pdfcreator = null;
    public string CreatedFile { get; private set; }
    public bool ActiveXError { get { return _ActiveXError; } }
    private bool _ActiveXError = false;

    private void _pdfcreator_eError()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("PDF Creator: " + _pdfcreator.cError.Description, "PDF Creator", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        try
        {
            if (_pdfcreator == null)
            {
                _pdfcreator = new clsPDFCreator();
                _pdfcreator.eReady += new __clsPDFCreator_eReadyEventHandler(_pdfcreator_eReady);
                _pdfcreator.eError += new __clsPDFCreator_eErrorEventHandler(_pdfcreator_eError);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _ActiveXError = true;
            Tools.LogException(ex, "PDFCreator");
        }
    }

    private void _pdfcreator_eReady()
    {
        //Returns path for generated PDF File
        CreatedFile = _pdfcreator.cOutputFilename;
    }

    public void PrintSheet(Worksheet xlSheet, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app, string file)
    {
        try
        {
            Initialize();
            if (_ActiveXError) return;

            string parameters = "/NoProcessingAtStartup";

            _pdfcreator = new clsPDFCreator();
            if (!_pdfcreator.cStart(parameters, false))
                MessageBox.Show("Nepodařilo se spustit \"PDFCreator\".", "Tisk sestavy", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            else
            {
                // Set parameters for saving the generating pdf automatically to a directory.
                clsPDFCreatorOptions opt = _pdfcreator.cOptions;
                opt.UseAutosave = 1;// Use auto save functionality.
                opt.UseAutosaveDirectory = 1;// Use directory for saving the file.

                string folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(file);
                string filename = Path.GetFileName(file);
                opt.AutosaveDirectory = folder; // Name of the output directory.
                opt.AutosaveFormat = 0;// Format of file is to be saved. 0 if for pdf.
                opt.AutosaveFilename = filename;// Name of the output file name.

                opt.Papersize = "A4";

                _pdfcreator.cOptions = opt;
                _pdfcreator.cClearCache();

                _pdfcreator.cDefaultPrinter = "PDFCreator";
                string defaultPrinter = _pdfcreator.cDefaultPrinter;                

                xlSheet.PrintOutEx(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, "PDFCreator", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

                // Wait till doc gets queued up.
                while (_pdfcreator.cCountOfPrintjobs != 1) ;

                // Start the printer.
                _pdfcreator.cPrinterStop = false;

                // Wait till all doc get converted to pdf.
                while (_pdfcreator.cCountOfPrintjobs != 0) ;

                // Stop the printer.
                _pdfcreator.cPrinterStop = true;

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _ActiveXError = true;
            Tools.LogException(ex, "PDFCreator");
        }
        finally
        {
            // Close the printer
            if (_pdfcreator is clsPDFCreator) _pdfcreator.cClose();
             _pdfcreator = null;
        }
    }
}
```

**But I need to achieve the same [with the new .NET COM wrapper](http://docs.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator/3.1/en/pdfcreator/com-interface/user-manual/how-to/use-com-from-dotnet/)**.
There is barely any documentation available and the object model is quite different. I do not know how to launch PDF Creator, set options on it and print in excel to the PDFCreator printer.

```
pdfforge.PDFCreator.UI.ComWrapper.PdfCreatorObj o = 
          new pdfforge.PDFCreator.UI.ComWrapper.PdfCreatorObj();
pdfforge.PDFCreator.UI.ComWrapper.Printers p = o.GetPDFCreatorPrinters;
string printerName = o.GetPDFCreatorPrinters.GetPrinterByIndex(0);
...?
```

(I know I can save as PDF from Excel but it has bugs with certain fonts)

Comment: What is PdfCreator?

Comment: http://docs.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator/3.1/en/

Comment: You should include that in your question.  Don't assume people know what it is.  Either tag it if a tag exists or include a link.

Comment: Already did that

Comment: What is precise problem?

Comment: @SMeaden The problem is that there are no examples online for basic tasks using this library. I have to solve the problem so either I get some help here or I post the solution here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the example in the install folder:

> C:\Program Files\PDFCreator\COM Scripts\C#.Net\COM_TestForm

Moreover the whole project is on GitHub with source code:

https://github.com/pdfforge/PDFCreator

I have modified my method accordingly. The problem was that my project targeted .NET 4.5 and COMWrapper 4.5.1, so build failed not finding pdfcreator namespace. I have downloaded PDF Creator from Git and built COMWrapper for 4.5 and it works now.

Only there is some bug calling `jobQueue.ReleaseCom()`, worked around reusing one Queue.

```
public static class PDFCreatorHelper
{
    public static string ErrorText { get; private set; }
    public static string CreatedFile { get; private set; }
    private static pdfforge.PDFCreator.UI.ComWrapper.Queue jobQueue = null;

    public static void PrintSheet(Worksheet xlSheet, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app, string file)
    {
        ErrorText = null;
        CreatedFile = null;
        if (jobQueue == null) 
        {
            Type queueType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("PDFCreator.JobQueue");
            Activator.CreateInstance(queueType);
            jobQueue = new pdfforge.PDFCreator.UI.ComWrapper.Queue();
            jobQueue.Initialize();  //Reusing one instance for the application runtime
        }
        else
        {
            jobQueue.Clear(); //Delete jobs already put there
        }
        string folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(file);
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(file);
        string convertedFilePath = Path.Combine(folder, filename);

        try
        {
            //Actual print command
            xlSheet.PrintOutEx(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, "PDFCreator", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

            if (!jobQueue.WaitForJob(10))
            {
                ErrorText = string.Format("PDFCreator: tisk {0} nebyl spuštěn do 10 sekund.", file);
                Tools.LogError(ErrorText);
            }
            else
            {
                var printJob = jobQueue.NextJob;
                printJob.SetProfileByGuid("DefaultGuid");
                printJob.SetProfileSetting("OpenViewer","false");
                printJob.SetProfileSetting("OpenWithPdfArchitect", "false");
                printJob.SetProfileSetting("ShowProgress", "false");
                printJob.SetProfileSetting("TargetDirectory", folder);
                printJob.SetProfileSetting("ShowAllNotifications", "false");

                if (File.Exists(convertedFilePath)) File.Delete(convertedFilePath);
                printJob.ConvertTo(convertedFilePath);

                if (!printJob.IsFinished || !printJob.IsSuccessful)
                {
                    ErrorText = string.Format("PDFCreator: nepodařila se konverze souboru: {0}.", file);
                    Tools.LogError(ErrorText);
                }
                printJob = null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            Tools.LogException(err, "PDFCreator");
            ErrorText = err.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            CreatedFile = convertedFilePath;
            //If this is left uncommented, app hangs during the second run
            //jobQueue.ReleaseCom(); 
            //jobQueue = null;
        }
    }
}
```